# When I am going List task from task queue(pull), I get an error

Tags: php, google-app-engine, task-queue, pull-queue

When I am going List task from task queue(pull) at GAE, I get an error. Please give me solution:

I am using AEQ library: https://github.com/tomwalder/php-appengine-pull-queue

My code is

```
include_once 'AEQ/Task.php';
include_once 'AEQ/Queue.php';

//$obj_task = new AEQ\Task();
$obj_queue = new AEQ\Queue('ondemand-image-task-queues');

// List Tasks

foreach($obj_queue->listTasks() as $obj_task) {
   echo $obj_task->getName();
}
```

I got an error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'RuntimeException' with message
>   'Failed to execute call [QueryTasks] with: 9 (PERMISSION_DENIED)' in
>   /base/data/home/apps/s~apigraymatics/1.390942967888630935/public/pull/AEQ/Queue.php:223
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /base/data/home/apps/s~project/1.390942967888630935/public/pull/AEQ/Queue.php(197):
>   AEQ\Queue->makeCall('QueryTasks',
>   Object(google\appengine\TaskQueueQueryTasksRequest),
>   Object(google\appengine\TaskQueueQueryTasksResponse)) #1
>   /base/data/home/apps/s~project/1.390942967888630935/public/pull/listtask.php(13):
>   AEQ\Queue->listTasks() #2 {main} thrown in
>   /base/data/home/apps/s~project/1.390942967888630935/public/pull/AEQ/Queue.php
>   on line 223

Please help me....

Comment: I'll look into this as soon as I can. Is the queue a "pull" queue?

Comment: yes.. It is pull queue..

Comment: Conversation transferred to GitHub https://github.com/tomwalder/php-appengine-pull-queue/issues/6